# dart chat-server sample, connecting from another machine

Tags: websocket, dart, dart-io

How do I connect to the chat-server example from another physical machine?

In
https://www.dartlang.org/slides/2012/06/io12/Bullseye-Your-first-Dart-app-Codelab- googleIO2012.pdf

I modify the chat-server, to bind 192.168.1.5 rather than 127.0.0.1.
I run the server from the command line.
From 192.168.1.9 in chrome, I connect to 192.168.1.5:1337/index.html.
On the client, I get the chat client page, however in the status window, I get:
    [system]: Connecting to Web socket
    [system]: web socket closed, retrying in 2 seconds
    [system]: Connecting to Web socket
    [system]: web socket closed, retrying in 4 seconds
etc

Using chrome on 192.168.1.5 works fine.

thx

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a firewall running on one of your machines (or both), where this port is blocked.